# How can I make separate picker view in one view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

My question about picker view. I have two textfield and these are connect picker view but when I try to make selection these two textfields text become same. I already try make tag for picker view but it didn't work. Here my code for better understand.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 3 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextFieldCellTeslim", for: indexPath) as! TextFieldCellTeslim
        let datePickerTeslim = UIPickerView()
        datePickerTeslim.delegate = self
        datePickerTeslim.dataSource = self
        datePickerTeslim.backgroundColor = .white
        cell.dateTextFieldTeslim.inputView = datePickerTeslim
        datePickerTeslim.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
    }
    if indexPath.section == 2 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextFieldCell", for: indexPath) as! TextFieldCell
        let datePicker = UIPickerView()
        datePicker.delegate = self
        datePicker.dataSource = self
        datePicker.backgroundColor = .white
        cell.dateTextField.inputView = datePicker
        datePicker.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
    }
```

These code show us connection of picker view.

```
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if component == 0 {

            secilenTarih = tarihArray[row]
            let path = IndexPath.init(row: pickerView.tag, section: 2)
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: path) as? TextFieldCell
            cell!.dateTextField.text = secilenTarih



            let pathTeslim = IndexPath.init(row: pickerView.tag, section: 3)
            let cellTeslim = tableView.cellForRow(at: pathTeslim) as? TextFieldCellTeslim
            cellTeslim!.dateTextFieldTeslim.text = secilenTarih



    }
    if component == 1 {

            secilenSaat = saatArray[row]
            let path = IndexPath.init(row: pickerView.tag, section: 2)
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: path) as? TextFieldCell
            cell!.dateTextField.text = secilenTarih + "  " + secilenSaat



            let pathTeslim = IndexPath.init(row: pickerView.tag, section: 3)
            let cellTeslim = tableView.cellForRow(at: pathTeslim) as? TextFieldCellTeslim
            cellTeslim!.dateTextFieldTeslim.text = secilenTarih + "  " + secilenSaat

    }
}
```

And here my picker view extension. I want to make separate selectable of these two textfield.How can I make it? I hope I asked clearly.

Comment: Maybe better option will be move `UIPicker` to `TextFieldCell` or even create custom `UITextField` with `UIPicker` implementation?

Comment: @Michcio Is there any way like picker view tag ? I assume in my delegate process I have some problem what do you think about?

Comment: To be honest - it is hard to understand without more context - if you want to fix your current approach without refactor, please, provide sample project i.e. on github. But I will suggest move this code outside of `UIViewController` - large classes are hard to understand and maintain.